# How to Pivot the Unpivoted Data Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a way which Pivot the Unpivoted Data, I have Three columns in the last of data which i want Pivot.

There are many ways available on Google to Unpivot the Data but there is nothing for Pivoting it.

I want to convert this data

[image]

into this

[image]

i would really appreciated the help thanks.

Comment: Need some more info here, can you explain in more detail also what you've tried.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highlight your table, use Get & Transform From Table (in the data ribbon). This will open a Power Query window. Here you can experiment fearlessly because it won't alter your source data.

Use Power Query to filter out the attributes you don't want, then pivot the attributes and change the resulting "DUE" column title name to "Due".

If you're not familiar with Power Query then prepare to be confused and amazed but, again, experiment fearlessly. I was angry the first time I found out about Power Query because of all the years I had needed it but had no idea it was there! :-)

Comment: Thank you very much I searched a lot to transform the data but nothing found but your answer revealed everything.